# How to "undeclare" volumes in docker image?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am writing a Dockerfile for setting up an image for testing a web application. I am basing it on the tutum/lamp image (https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-lamp/blob/master/Dockerfile) because that seems to be a good base to start from.

As part of my dockerfile, I want to create a mysql database and set up some stuff in it. However, the tutum/lamp image declares `VOLUME ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql" ]`, so if I understand correctly, any changes that I make to the MySQL database in the Dockerfile will not be persisted.

- Do I understand that correctly?

If yes,

- Is there a way to "undeclare" those volumes so that those directories will be part of the union file system like everything else?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the exact same thing. I edited the volumes out of tutum/lamp but when I tried to build it I got: `start-apache2.sh: no such file or directory`

Comment: @pguardiario: Did you clone all of the files from the tutum/lamp git directory? You need to get all the supporting files too, not only the Dockerfile. Also, make sure that you run `docker build` in the right directory.

Comment: yes I figured that out too. I got them both to build but I'm still having issues with moving the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really undeclare a volume, but you can build your own version of the original image by modifying its dockerfile.

Comment: Is there a way to get the docker file from an existing docker hub image?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible to change an existing container, so you have two options:

1. Take the Tutum container and build your own variant
2. Manage persistence of the tutum container using a data container.

## Data containers

Create a container that creates a data volume reference:

```
docker run -it --name dbvol -v /var/lib/mysql ubuntu env
```

This can then be used when running the mysql database to persist the data:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from dbvol -p 3306:3306 tutum/mysql:5.6
```

The data persists as long as the "dbvol" container exists. It can be deleted at any stage:

```
docker rm dbvol
```

Reference:

- http://blog.tutum.co/2014/05/27/containerize-your-database-volume-with-tutum-mysql-images/
- https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware of the "data container" principle, but I don't know how I would use it in conjunction with the Dockerfile script? I want to create a database and make several additions and changes to it in the script.

Comment: @Mikkel Then take the dockerfile used by Tutum and run it locally to create your own image. Using local volumes for data is also a lot more efficient from a performance point of view (Aufs is slow). The data container pattern is simply a useful trick to ensure the data volume doesn't get deleted with the container (volumes are only deleted when all container references are gone)

Comment: I was coming to that conclusion myself also (building my own tutum-like image). I was just wondering if there was a way to "undeclare" a volume. If you post your suggestion of building my own image as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There has been no change to this problem space in years, so I have created [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit) as a workaround to "undeclare" a volume by editing the metadata of a downloaded image.