# Overriding VOLUME directive in a Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm building my own image on top of `docker.io/mongo:3.2`, but I have a problem with persisting some changes (creating new users) in the build process.

I'm aware that this happens because the users are created in the `/data/db`, which is defined as `VOLUME` in the original MongoDB Dockerfile.

My question is if there is a way I can add users during the build process and make those changes persist the build process.

Alternatively, if that isn't possible, how can I add the DB users during the build process of my image?

Comment: I have asked a similar question before, and you may benefit from some of the answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315680/how-to-undeclare-volumes-in-docker-image