# Is it a docker best practice to use volume for the code?

Tags: docker

> The VOLUME instruction should be used to expose any database storage area, configuration storage, or files/folders created by your docker container. You are strongly encouraged to use VOLUME for any mutable and/or user-serviceable parts of your image.

will you store your code in volume?

Such as your jar files. It could be a little convenient to deploy the application without rebuilding the image.
Are there any considerations if storing the code in volume? like performance, security or others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't recommend using a `VOLUME` statement inside the Dockerfile for anything with current versions of docker (current being any version of docker since the introduction of named volumes). Including a `VOLUME` command has multiple downsides, including:

- possible inability to change contents at that location of the image with any later steps or child images (this behavior appears to be different with different scenarios and different versions of docker)
- potential to create volumes with just a hash for the name that clutter up the `docker volume ls` output and are very difficult to find and reuse later if you needed the data inside
- for your changing code, if you place it in a volume and recreate your container from a new version of the image, the volume will still have the old copy of your code unless you update that volume yourself (the key feature of volumes is persistent data that you want to keep between image versions)

I do recommend putting your data in a volume that you define on the `docker run` command line or inside a docker-compose.yml. Volumes defined there can have a name or map back to a path on the docker host. And you can make any folder or file a volume without needing to define it in the Dockerfile. Volumes defined at this step doesn't impact the image, allowing you to extend an image without being locked out of making changes to a directory.

For your code, it is a common best practice to inject code with a volume if it is interpreted (e.g. javascript) or already compiled (e.g. a jar file) during application development. You would define the volume on the container (not the Dockerfile), and overlay the code or binaries that were also copied into the image using the same filenames. This allows you to rapidly iterate in development without frequently rebuilding the image. Depending on the application, you may be able to live reload the code, otherwise, a container restart should be all that's needed to see the latest change. And once development is finished, you rebuild the image with your current code and ship that to someone that can use it without needing the volume mount for the code.

I've also [blogged about my concerns with volumes inside of Dockerfiles](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/) if you'd like to see more details on this.

Comment: I got that volume in dockerfile is terrible.  
Back to my question. I also can overlay the code by logging into the container, right? so how come it's a common best practice to inject code with a volume.

Comment: If you log into a container with an exec, you shouldn't have your developer stack inside the container, so you're typically left editing with vim and not checking the result back into git. The container is also cattle, replaced with a new container, losing your hand edits. Injecting code from the developer workstation as a volume let's the developer keep their code where it already is.

Comment: that makes sense at some scenarios. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify that VOLUME in Dockerfiles is also not good for an output directory of build artifacts on an ephemeral image that is used to build things.

Comment: You wrote "And once development is finished, you rebuild the image with your current code and ship that to someone that can use it without needing the volume mount for the code." Does this mean that you setup a separate build for development and production, e.g., with two Docker Compose files? Then, you would omit the volume from the Compose file for production.

Comment: @PetriK same Dockerfile, so same image. The compose file in development will often differ from production for lots of reasons (the configuration will point to a different db, hostname, etc).

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> It could be a little convenient to deploy the application without rebuilding the image.

Instead of that, it has a lot of advantages to encapsulate your application version inside an image build. You can easily deploy your app only deploying the image, so the fact that you use a volume for app code leads you to orchestrate some other deployment method to update that volume too.

And you have to (eventually) match the *jar* version with the proper image version.

Regarding security or performance, I don't think that there are special considerations.

Anyway, it is not a common approach to use volumes for that. And as @BMitch say, using `VOLUME` inside Dockerfile is some tricky.