# GitLab on Docker: how to persist user data between deployments?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, persistence, docker-volume

I am using the official GitLab Docker image.

I want to have pre-configured user accounts available in my GitLab container to be used for tests.

But user accounts are saved in a volume, so I can't just `commit` and `push` the GitLab image after having created my test users.

***So: how should I persist them?***

One way would be to create them on startup using the API after each new deployment, but this is quite slow/cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it's not going to be as easy as committing and pushing a Docker image because of the VOLUMEs declared in the gitlab-ce and gitlab-ee images.

Perhaps you can [backup and restore the instances](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html)? So, create a backup of the state you want including the pre-configured accounts, and then restore that onto new GitLab containers after they're started?