# What is the use of VOLUME in this official Dockerfile of postgresql

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I found the following code in the Dockerfile of official postgresql. https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/Dockerfile

```
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data
RUN mkdir -p "$PGDATA" && chown -R postgres:postgres "$PGDATA" && chmod 777 "$PGDATA" # this 777 will be replaced by 700 at runtime (allows semi-arbitrary "--user" values)
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I want to know what is the purpose of VOLUME in this regard.

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

As per my understanding it will create a new storage volume when we start a container and that storage volume will also be deleted permanently when the container is removed (`docker stop contianerid; docker rm containeid`)

**Then if the data is not going to persist then why to use this. Because VOLUME are used if we want the data to persist.**

**My question is w.r.t what is its use if the postgres data is only going to remain only till the container is running and after that everything is wiped out. If i have done lot of work and in the end everything is gone then whats the use.**

Comment: You want to read https://4sysops.com/archives/introduction-to-docker-bind-mounts-and-volumes/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding "VOLUME" instruction in DockerFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935435/understanding-volume-instruction-in-dockerfile)

Comment: I am asking w.r.t to data persistance. Because its going to be temporary. I want to know its usage. This is different from mounting because in mounting its understood, but in this case its just going to create a volume with hash name and later delete it after container is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding it will create a new storage volume when we start a container and that storage volume will also be deleted permanently when the container is removed (docker stop contianerid; docker rm containeid)

If you run a container with the `--rm` option, anonymous volumes are deleted when the container exits. If you do not pass the `--rm` option when creating the container, then the `-v` option to `docker container rm` will also delete volumes. Otherwise, these anonymous volumes will persist after a stop/rm.

That said, anonymous volumes are difficult to manage since it's not clear which volume contains what data. Particularly with images like postgresql, I would prefer if they removed the `VOLUME` line from their Dockerfile, and instead provided a compose file that defined the volume with a name. You can see more about what the `VOLUME` line does and why it creates problems in my [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516433/596285).

Comment: you are right, whenever i run with --rm then the volume gets deleted immidiately after the container stops. But i havent tried the other way like -d or without --rm. But as you mentioned even if they exist its will be difficult to understand by their random names for what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of how *volumes* works is almost correct but not completely.

As you stated, when you create a container from an image defining a `VOLUME`, docker will indeed create an *anonymous volume* (i.e. with a random name).

When you stop/remove the container the volume itself will not be deleted and will still be accessible by the `docker volume` family of commands.

Indeed in order to remove a container and delete associated volumes you have to use the `-v` flag as in `docker rm -v container-name`. This command will remove the container and delete all the *anonymous volumes* associated with it (named volume will never be deleted unless explicitly requested via `docker volume rm volume-name`).

So to sum up the `VOLUME` directive inside a Dockerfile is used to identify those places that will host persistent data and ensuring the following:

- data will survive the life of the container by default
- data can be shared with other containers (i.e. `--volumes-from`)

The most important aspect to me is that it also serves as a sort of implicit documentation for your user to let them know where the persistent state is kept (so that they can *name* the volumes via the `-v` flag of `docker run`).

Comment: `The most important aspect to me is that it also serves as a sort of implicit documentation for your user to let them know where the persistent state is kept (so that they can name the volumes via the -v flag of docker run).` indirectly this can be a good reason also.

`--volumes-from` definitely sometimes.

`data will survive the life of the container by default`:  even thought the volume is still existing, but as mentioned by @BMitch `anonymous volumes are difficult to manage since it's not clear which volume contains what data.`

Comment: Anyhow i was confused mainly because i run my containers using --rm. then the volume is always deleted when the container stops.