# Docker create volumes in Dockerfile and compile app on it

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

In my docker django project i need for read/write purpose to create a volumes in my Dockerile and install/run app on it.

i found this article : [DockerFile on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935435/understanding-volume-instruction-in-dockerfile) but sincerly i don't understand more about it.

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN mkdir /Code

VOLUME /var/lib/cathstudio/data
WORKDIR /Code

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /Code/

ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

at my original file i add the `VOLUME /var/lib/cathstudio/data` instruction, but after that how can i say to the rest of my code to use that volumes for WORKDIR, install requirements.txt, copy code and run app?

i don't what to specify it in RUN statement with -v directive after build, i would integrate the volume creation and manage directly in dockerfile.

So many thanks in advance

Comment: The Dockerfile you've shown looks correct, and is the normal way to use Docker.  Why do you think you want the code in volumes?

Answer (score 1):

for anything expect `pip` you may specify workdir once:

```
WORKDIR /var/lib/cathstudio/data
```

for pip use `-t` or `--target`:

```
pip install -t /var/lib/cathstudio/data
```

> -t, --target
>
> ```
> Install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>. Use --upgrade to replace existing
> ```
>
> packages in  with new versions

Comment: thus RUN pip install -t /var/lib/cathstudio/data -r requirements.txt correct? thanks

Comment: and do not forget to set your PYTHONPATH to `/var/lib/cathstudio/data` so your code knows where to look for the installed modules

Comment: In DockerFIle? i would to distribute my application for many people, i would automate mutch thinks possible

Comment: yes in docker file add ENV and ARG like so `ENV PYTHONPATH /var/lib/cathstudio/data`

Comment: but i have to modify also ENTRYPOINT COPY or othe command with new path /var/lib/cathstudio/data?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 become ENTRYPOINT python /var/lib/cathstudio/data/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 or just ENTRYPOINT python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 ? So many thanks