# Default volumes created while running mongodb images

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, containers, docker-volume

I am trying to run `mongodb` using docker-compose.
Every time I restart the containers, I see that mongo creates default volumes with random names and the number of volume grows.

[image]

Why these volumes are created and how can I avoid them.

My `docker-compose.yml` for mongo is as follows:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - ts-net
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db_data:/data/db/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking:

> Why these volumes are created…?

The volumes you speak about are called **anonymous volumes**. They can typically be created by the Dockerfile directive `VOLUME`, e.g.:

[github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/5.0/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/5faa46234f12b4af395ffa554c3ab28fc6d02ed3/5.0/Dockerfile#L113)

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

These volumes have indeed the drawbacks that *(i)* their automatically-generated name does not refer to the image they were created from, and that *(ii)* they are not removed once the corresponding container is removed (unless we [use the CLI option `docker run --rm`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-volumes)).

> how can I avoid them…?

1. If you're developing your own base image, just avoid using the `VOLUME` directive.
2. Otherwise, the best way to cope with existing images relying on the `VOLUME` directive is to *(i)* figure out which paths are associated to a given volume, and *(ii)* associate these paths to a **named volume** within the `docker-compose.yml` specification, namely:

```yaml
services:

  db:
    image: mongo:5.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - 'db_data:/data/db'
      - 'db_config:/data/configdb'
    networks:
      - db-net

networks:
  db-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
  db_config:
    driver: local
```

#### Additional references

For more details/remarks about `VOLUME`s, see also:

- the SO question [Why do some Docker images have no VOLUME defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61759981/9164010) by [@s3-89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12926082/s3-89)
- this nice [blog article](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/) by [@BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (newbie) with unnamed / tangling Docker Images and Volumes. After much research and experimentation (and the first answer posted here) I now have a DOCKER-COMPOSE.YAML the can be used to build a generic 3-Tier MERN Stack App that is Dockerized into three Containers. And all the Docker objects are named explicitly by the YAML file.

```
Containers:
<appname>-frontend
<appname>-backend
<appname>-database

Images:
<appname>-frontend
<appname>-backend
<appname>-database

Volumes:
<appname>-frontend
<appname>-backend
<appname>-database (dg config)
<appname>-mongodb (external persistent db)
```

My 3-TIER MERN App DOCKER-COMPOSE.YAML:

```
#
version: '3'
#
#  V O L U M E S -- NOTE: can't use ${APP_NAME} here, and internal are auto-prefixed with <appname>_<name-specified>
#  -------------
#
volumes:
  frontend-volume:  # our Frontend/Client execution volume
    name: "badbank-frontend"
    external: false  # temporary, build specific
#
  backend-volume:  # our Backend/Server execution volume
    name: "badbank-backend"
    external: false  # temporary, build specific
#
  database-volume:  # our Database configuration volume
    name: "badbank-database"
    external: false  # temporary, build specific
#
  mongodb-volume:  # our Database/MongoDB storage volume
    name: "badbank-mongodb"
    external: true  # keep after all Containers are destroyed
#
services:
  #
  #  F R O N T E N D
  #  ---------------
  frontend:
    # frontend, client, app ui
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-frontend
    # use the shared .env file for all 3 Tiers
    env_file:
      - .\.env  # shared environment vars for all 3-Tiers
      - .\.env.${NODE_ENV:-development}  # "development" to override the "production" vars in the 'Dockerfile'
    build:
      context: frontend  # build from \frontend
      args:
        APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    ports:
      - '${APP_FRONTEND_PORT:-3000}:${APP_FRONTEND_PORT:-3000}'
    volumes:
      - frontend-volume:/exe/frontend  # temporary volume
    restart: always
    networks:
      - react-express  # frontend to backend connection
    depends_on:
      - backend
  #
  #  B A C K E N D
  #  -------------
  backend:
    # backend, server, app internals
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-backend
    # use the shared .env file for all 3 Tiers
    env_file:
      - .\.env  # shared environment vars for all 3-Tiers
      - .\.env.${NODE_ENV:-development}  # "development" to override the "production" vars in the 'Dockerfile'
    build:
      context: backend  # build from \backend
      args:
        APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    ports:
      - '${APP_BACKEND_PORT:-8080}:${APP_BACKEND_PORT:-8080}'
    volumes:
      - backend-volume:/exe/frontend  # temporary volume
    restart: always
    networks:
      - react-express  # frontend to backend connection
      - express-mongo  # backend to database connection
    depends_on:
      - database
  #
  #  D A T A B A S E
  #  ---------------
  database:
    # database, db, data store, app persistent data
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-database
    # use the shared .env file for all 3 Tiers
    env_file:
      - .\.env  # shared environment vars for all 3-Tiers
      - .\.env.${NODE_ENV:-development}  # "development" to override the "production" vars in the 'Dockerfile'
    build:
      context: database  # build from \database
      args:
        APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    ports:
      - '${APP_DATABASE_PORT:-27017}:${APP_DATABASE_PORT:-27017}'
    volumes:
      - database-volume:/data/configdb  # temporary volume -- NOTE: /data/configdb/ is the path required by MongoDB
      - mongodb-volume:/data/db  # persist our database in this volume -- NOTE: /data/db/ is the path required by MongoDB
    restart: always
    networks:
      - express-mongo  # backend to database connection
#
networks:
  react-express:
  express-mongo:
#
```