# Skip Updating crates.io index when using cargo run

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a simple Program written in Rust.
When I type `cargo run` in terminal it always shows:

```
Updating crates.io index...
```

And this takes around 40 seconds.
But I just wan to execute my Program and I think cargo does not need to update the index every time I run the Program, since this makes testing very slow...

Is there an option to skip that?

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out:

Since I am running cargo in a Docker container, I need to store the cargo cache persistently because it resets every time the container restarts.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this?

Comment: Ok, found it: set environment variable CARGO_HOME

Comment: Do you by chance know how to do that from the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Vou can define volumes inside the Dockerfile (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46992367/15220905), but this is not what would help, since by doing that, they are just temporary. Use the `-v`option in your docker command instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is [The Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/) that contains all the information you'd ever want to know about `cargo`. See [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#no-index-update) for disabling index update.

I've tried to use this feature myself, and here's the command that worked:

```
cargo +nightly run -Z no-index-update
```

The `+nightly` thing is new to me as well, but I find it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html?highlight=nightly#unstable-features).

Comment: `error: no such subcommand: \`+nightly\``

Comment: I'm sure this works. Please write the full command that you tried to execute.

Comment: `cargo +nightly run -Z no-index-update`. I have cargo 1.60 if it helps

Comment: Try `rustup show` and see if you actually have a nightly toolchain installed.. Although I've no idea what's going on here..

Comment: Probably a sign that Rust was not installed using rustup (and that you should start using rustup)

Comment: `error: unknown -Z flag specified:  no-index-update`

Answer (score 3):

This answer has been brought up by users `thefeiter` and `Captain Fim` but I think a more complete answer could be cool rust/linux newcomers

When we use docker run, the index is updated every time the container is run because the cache is not shared between runs. So to skip the index update, as Captain Fim mentioned, you need to set the `CARGO_HOME` environment variable on the container. This environment variable should contain the path to a persistent folder. One simple solution is using the docker volumes to share cache between host and container.

In my case, I created at cargo_home folder in my project (could be somewhere else) on my host. I have passed the whole project folder to the container and set the docker env variable of CARGO_HOME to the container path to the cargo_home folder.

The command to build my app looks like this

`docker run --rm --user "$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" -e CARGO_HOME=/usr/src/myapp/cargo_home -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp rust-compiler cargo build`

The first time you will run this command, it will take some time, but you should see the cargo_home folder getting filled with files. The next time you run the command, it should use the cargo_home folder as cache. This should be almost instant if your app source code did not change.

Comment: Can I also set the `CARGO_HOME` environment variable from my `Dockerfile` instead? 

I'm using `docker-compose` instead of `docker run`.

Comment: If you are reffering to the ARG command in the Dockerfile, then I don't think this is the good approach. IIRC, ARG in Dockerfile is more of a env variable when the container is being built (before running the built container). If you are using docker-compose then you can use the `environment` key on your service in the docker-composer.yml. See [doc here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers). This `environment` key in docker-compose is the same as the `-e ` option when calling docker.