# Docker creates a new volume everytime I do docker compose up

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a docker-compose file that spins up several services. I just got an error stating I ran out of disk space so I typed "docker system df" and saw I have 21 volumes. If I have 3 docker containers with each having a volume attached to them, why its showing me a total count of 21 volumes?

I am using AWS EC2. This is my compose file, is there anything wrong with the way I have the volumes set? The postgres data got persisted when I shutdown and restart, I am just confused aboutthe volume size and the message that I can not rebuild due to no space on a T2 Large instance.

```js
version: "3"
services:
  nftapi:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '443:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - postgres
      
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
  pgadmin:
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

[image]

Comment: The anonymous volume for your application's `node_modules` directory looks odd, particularly on EC2: you wouldn't want to overwrite the image's library tree with an anonymous volume, and you wouldn't generally want to push the application source to a cloud deployment separately from its Docker image.  That's the only non-bind-mount volume you show, though.  Does your image declare unnecessary `VOLUME` that would result in more anonymous volumes being created?

Answer (score 4):

A Docker image's Dockerfile can contain a [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) directive.  This is an instruction to Docker that tells it that some container directory contains data that needs to be persisted, and Docker should always ensure a volume of some sort is mounted on that directory.

More specifically, the `postgres` image [declares](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a83005b407ee6d810413500d8a041c957fb10cf0/14/bullseye/Dockerfile#L180)

```sh
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Your Compose setup doesn't mount anything on that specific directory.  Because of this, Docker creates an anonymous volume and mounts it there for you.  This isn't specific to the `postgres` image and other containers in your stack may have similar local data directories.  Those anonymous volumes are what you're seeing in the `docker system df` output (`docker volume ls` will also show them).

In [a later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673547/volumes-being-created-anonymously-instead-of-named-and-re-created-on-every-compo) you also note that Compose has trouble finding these anonymous volumes, and it's better to not rely on this functionality.  Make sure you're mounting a host directory or named volume for these data directories via Compose `volumes:`.

Answer (score 1):

if your main containers are up and running run

```
docker volume prune
```

and it should remove any volumes that are detached or unused by any container
i make it a habit to run periodically on my aws instance

```
docker system prune
```