# Volumes being created anonymously instead of named and re-created on every compose up / down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few docker containers that I start and stop with docker-compose up / down. Inside the docker-compose.yml I have defined a volume for each container. To what I understood, these should appear as a named volume under var/lib/docker/volumes but all I am seeing is a bunchof cryptic directories that also increase in count everytime I restart containers.

Everytime I restart my containers, the database is empty again when I thought I am using volumes to avoid it beeing like this. I want to persist the data.

Am I doing something wrong I am missing?

```
version: "3"
services:
  nftapi:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
      
    networks:
      - postgres
      
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
  pgadmin:
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres
 
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

Screen of volume dirs

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Docker Hub `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) keeps its data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` (see ["Where to store data" in the extended description](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#where-to-store-data)).  You need to change the bind mount so that's the second directory named there.

```yaml
volumes:
  - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  #                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  #            second half must be this exact path
```

This is why you're not seeing data persisted in the host directory; it's getting mounted on the wrong path.

Meanwhile, the image's `Dockerfile` [contains a `VOLUME` declaration for that directory](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a83005b407ee6d810413500d8a041c957fb10cf0/14/bullseye/Dockerfile#L180).  That causes Docker to create an anonymous volume for that directory if nothing else is mounted there.  The [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) documentation notes:

> Anonymous volumes are not removed by default [by `docker-compose down`]. However, as they don’t have a stable name, they will not be automatically mounted by a subsequent `up`.

So that's why you're also not seeing database data preserved across restarts either; fixing the mount path will address this.

(In [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670267/docker-creates-a-new-volume-everytime-i-do-docker-compose-up) you were asking where the extra volumes came from, and it's the anonymous volumes created by the Dockerfile `VOLUME`.  [@larsks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673590) has a good discussion on the different between named volumes and bind mounts; the anonymous volumes they refer to at the end of their answer are the same `VOLUME` mechanic.)

Comment: I edited the volume path as described to  volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data   but everytime I add data to the database and to docker-compose down and up again. The data is gone..

Answer (score 2):

You are not making use of named volumes.  When the left side of your volume configuration refers to an existing host path, this is a "bind mount", not a named volume. When you start your compose stack, this configuration:

```
    volumes:
    - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
```

Means that the host path `/data/postgres` is mounted on `/data/postgres` in the container.

A named volume configuration would look like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
      
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - postgres_data:/data/postgres
    env_file:
    - docker.env
    networks:
    - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

You can read more about volumes [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). The docker-compose syntax is in the [syntax reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).

The other volumes you see in the output of e.g. `docker volumes` probably correspond to anonymous volumes configured in the images you're using. For example, the pgadmin image has a volume mounted at `/var/lib/pgadmin`:

```
$ docker pull docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4
$ docker inspect docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4 | jq .[0].ContainerConfig.Volumes
{
  "/var/lib/pgadmin": {}
}
```

Comment: Does that explain why everytime i docker-compose down and up again, my database is empty?

Comment: No, I think @David Maze covers that.